# Storing text files on sdcard Problem

Tags: android

how to  store text files or pdf in sdcard and then show it in android emulator in Eclipse  ?
i am  newbie to android.i have not written any code.
please tell me how to accomplish this.any refernce and open source code would be really helpfull

Comment: What's the problem? Share the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get the root directory with the static method

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

which returns a File. Then you can work like in traditional Java with it's I/O API. Inside the emulator, in your code, you can navigate through files and directories with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: i did adb push yourfile.xxx /sdcard/yourfile.xxx.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but you asked how to do it in code, inside an app.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give us a bit more info than that.  What code have you written to accomplish this?  What problem exactly are you trying to solve?

eLance is a better place to get your code written for you ;)  We're here to help you.